# Google App Engine deploy error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

error messages launcher gave

```
09:30 PM Getting current resource limits.
2013-07-26 21:30:11,411 ERROR appcfg.py:1986 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4252, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4243, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2402, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3979, in __call__
    return method()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2980, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml, yaml_file_basename)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2929, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1956, in DoUpload
    self.resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 386, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 357, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 387, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
2013-07-26 21:30:11 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I don't know whether it is the Net connection problem. Google is not stable here.I have search some solutions, they all said something wrong with proxy or something. How do I solve this problem.

Comment: I use google two step auth , so I should upload my projcet,with [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth)

Answer (score 0):

It said "getaddrinfo failed" - it should be a temporary problem that your DNS cannot resolve the domain to IP. Try again later.